# Trying to test my gradle project through command prompt with arguments but not successfully

Tags: gradle

gradle -D  D:project clean test -DargLine="-DplatformName='Windows' -DbrowserName='chrome' -DtestType='PC'  -DwebURL=https://gmail.com -Dome_username=abc -Dome_password=abc@231 -Dauth_user=xyz -Dauth_pass=sde -Dchild_user=ad -Dchild_pass=Pda!  -Dcucumber.filter.tags='@scenario_dcsta_01'"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.